# Object tag rendering html document.How can i apply css to that document?

Tags: html, css

below object tag rending html doc internally to display  svg image.but getting scroll bars with that object.

```html
<object class="borderlines" id="" type="image/svg+xml" data="https://qa-static-default.sf-cdn.com/renderer/imagerenderer/svgconversion?svgPath=http://swiftbuckets.sf-cdn.com/v1/cmg/qacell10/cdm/20c42364439845648af86bfb317e5481/4&amp;imageHeight=200&amp;imageFormat=JPG&amp;publishedTime=1549521045 "
  style="width: 100px;height: 100px;display: inline-block;position: relative"></object>

<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=0.1">
  <title>svgconversion (271×200)</title>
</head>
<body style="margin: 0px;">
  <img style="-webkit-user-select: none;" src="https://qa-static-default.sf-cdn.com/renderer/imagerenderer/svgconversion?svgPath=http://swiftbuckets.sf-cdn.com/v1/cmg/qacell10/cdm/20c42364439845648af86bfb317e5481/4&amp;imageHeight=200&amp;imageFormat=JPG&amp;publishedTime=1549521045">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You set the width and height to 100px, If your image/content is larger you'll have scrollbars...

Comment: Is there any way to remove scrolls for this image ?

Comment: Note: Firefox correctly scales the content.

Comment: Yes i required like that only @ItayGal.I want all svg image fit into 100px without having scrollbars.

Comment: I have a solution, but I cant figure out from where the HTML is being loaded in the `object` tag since I have never worked with the `object` tag before

Comment: and this issue i am getting in chrome browser only

Answer (score 0):

i cant comment, but maybe this can help you https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=tryresponsive_image_mediaq2